# Does the Operative talent "Flash Powder" work on bosses that are immune to the incapacitate from Flash Bang?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Specifically raid bosses -  are they affected by the accuracy debuff?

I know a number of other similar effects (i.e. from Snipers and Marauders) *do* work on raid bosses. Wondering if this would be a useful addition to my Operative's toolkit, or if it's a waste of two talent points.

Comment: I know as a tank assassin, that the accuracy debuff from discharging my dark charge works on all bosses.

Comment: @lyrion yeah, the thing that's unique about Flash Powder is that it's linked to an ability (Flash Bang) to which bosses are immune. Hence the question.

Comment: Hmm, i would suggest trying it out, i mean you can always respec right? :p

Comment: An addition to this should be, "if it does apply to bosses, when does it apply? As Flash bang never starts it can't end to be applied. So, does it wait the full 5 seconds or apply instantly?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NO.**

It doesn't work. Attempted it tonight in HM EV on the first and second bosses. No debuff applied either time.

Comment: Guess you will have to let the accuracy debuffs to the darkness sith assasins ;)

Comment: And Powertechs. And Marauders. And Snipers.